# How can i sort structure according to equal elements?

Tags: c, sorting, struct

My struct has 3 int array. Like this:

---

```
A[]:  1   2   3   4   5    6    7    8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
B[]:  2   3   1   1   2    2    4    3   3   1   3   4   3   4   1
C[]:  40  20  50  70  130  100  170  70  60  20  20  20  20  20  70
```

---

I want sort my struct according to two criterion.

First one is: increasing C-Array

Second one is : increasing B-Array for every equal elements of C-Array.

After sorting the arrays must be in this way:

---

```
A[]:  10  2   11  13  12  14  1   3   9   4   15  8   6    5    7  
B[]:  1   3   3   3   4   4   2   1   3   1   1   3   2    2    4    
C[]:  20  20  20  20  20  20  40  50  60  70  70  70  100  130  170
```

---

I did first criterion with bubble sorting but second one is more complicated.

How can i make this?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: And in the next edit it will have 4 arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The essential factor that determines the order of elements in sorting is the result of comparison, in your example, the comparison is first based on comparing the two elements in array B, and only when they are equal in array B, then compare in array A. You can make a compare function like this:

```
// A and B are two arrays, i and j are the two indexes for comparing
int compare(int i, int j) {
    if (C[i] < C[j]) return -1;
    else if (C[i] > C[j]) return 1;
    else { // compare in B
        if (B[i] < B[j]) return -1;
        else if (B[i] > B[j]) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

And then you could apply this compare function into your sort function, by replacing where you compare elements, e.g. if you have code like `if (C[i] < C[j]) swap(...);` do `if (compare(i, j) < 0) swap(...);` instead.

If you are using standard C's `qsort` function, you will need to adjust the function to accept pointer to the struct array elements though.

Comment: +1. It might help TC a lot if you posted an example of how your compare function is thrown into a generic sorter, like `qsort()`. TC might have done a "wrap your own" sort, and the loosely coupled modularity of your compare function could be overlooked/underappreciated.

Comment: You are right, updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But i changed my question because first i made mistake. Can you help me this form?

Comment: @Waox so you mean A array does not take into account when sorting?

Comment: @fluter Yes, exactly. A array doesn't join to sorting. Sorting will be according to B and C array. But be aware of 3 arrays in one struct.

Comment: @Waox The function is basically the same, it just the arrays names that changed.

Comment: @fluter But If i use this function i think A-array won't change. It will stay first condition.

Comment: @Waox No, the compare function only determines the order of elements, it does not change the order, or swap them, you have to swap the required array elements, in this case, you swap all of A, B and C arrays. The compare function remain the same, no matter how many arrays are there.

Comment: @fluter I see. I don't know how can i use this func in qsort because there are more than one array.

Comment: @Waox This function is primarily for the bubble sort function you write, if used for `qsort` it needs to change a bit.